# Braided monoidal category of (generalized) operator algebras

Tags: ct.category-theory, mp.mathematical-physics, oa.operator-algebras

In the paper "[Quantum Collections](https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.2994)" Kornell (2016) proved that the category of $W^*$ (von Neumann) (and iirc also $C^*$) algebras, equipped with a suitable choice of tensor product, forms a symmetric monoidal category. Naturally, one would be tempted to ask if one could get a *braided* but not symmetric monoidal category by enlarging the collection of objects, or by equipping objects with extra structure.

Are there any known braided monoidal categories of (generalized) operator algebras?